# CXF Weblogic - Override CXF logger to Slf4j

Tags: cxf, weblogic-10.x

We are using Apache CXF 2.5.2 for webservice client proxies. We use weblogic 10.3.4. To override the CXF logger we use the following option:

```
-Dorg.apache.cxf.Logger=org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Slf4jLogger
```

For the `org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Slf4jLogger`, we've included the `cxf-common-utilities-2.5.2` in our build.

When we try to deploy to weblogic we get the following exception:

```
[ERROR] Target state: deploy failed on Server AdminServer
[ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/wsee/jaxws/spi/WLSProvider
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/client/basics.html#wp1066820), your WebService client should have `wseeclient.jar` as it's runtime dependency. If the problems is still there, then include `wlfullclient.jar` (see [Creating a wlfullclient.jar for JDK 1.6 client applications](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/client/jarbuilder.html#wp1078098) ).